# Why I am getting error of "Use of unresolved identifier 'GIDSignIn'"?

Tags: ios, swift4, google-signin

I am trying to implement it from [google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) but failed in Swift 4. Maybe the code is outdated. How can I solve the issue in swift 4?
My pod file is for Swift 4.

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

and my AppDelegate file is looking like this.

[Appdelegate](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/C9v2jSZXnw/)

Comment: Try to print detailed error, or describe at which point this error occurs like this error comes at build time, etc.

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'GIDSignIn'

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pod file to include the following:

```
pod 'GTMAppAuth'

pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

And also use this import in your AppDelegate:

```
import GoogleSignIn
```

Hope this helps someone out.